# How do I run Django project in Python 2.7 without using PyCharm IDE

Tags: django, python-2.7, pycharm

How do I  run Django project in Python 2.7 on windows 7 32 bits without using PyCharm IDE?

Comment: PyCharm IDE has nothing to do with Python or Django Project, it's just a tool, you can you text editor for instance. What have you actually tried to run your Django project ? Provide some code please

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by `Command Prompt` or `Terminal`

Use this command `$ python manage.py runserver`

For more information check [this official documentation of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:

1. Open a windows console `(cmd)`
2. Install python from: [official website](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)
3. Install django via pip: `pip install django`
4. Create your django-project: `django-admin startproject project_name`
5. Run it via: `python manage.py runserver 8000`